# IE8+IE9 - background-image of body doesn't fully load, there isn't shown

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, background-image

I have a landing page with a a background image of about 880kilobytes in size.
I set the background with this rule:

```
background: #fff url(bg1.png) no-repeat left top;
```

Problem is, in IE8 and 9 I don't see the background. It seems that it doesn't completely download the image. Using the network profiler on IE9, and even Fiddler, I see there's a problem loading this specific image.
Furthermore, if i open a new tab and navigate directly to the image, thus loading it, and then I refresh the landing page - the background image appears! So annoying.........
I guess it's a problem with IE caching mechanism?
The same thing happens when I put it in an img tag. only takes space but not shown.

EDIT:
upon further analysis i can point out the following:
1. in fiddler i see the request is made, and completed with code 200 but gets aborted by IE for some reason.
2. it is random. if i keep refreshing without cache, it can sometimes show the image, and sometimes not show it.

help?

Comment: and apparently i don't know how to linebreak here. good job me.

Comment: it's possible that the image itself has some kind of corruption that IE doesn't like. I'd suggest opening it in an image editor and re-saving it. If that is the problem, doing that might help.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing, providing of course the path to bg1.png is correct. Is the image indeed in the same directory as your source code?

Using a CSS reset is a good practise anyway, and may fix your problem:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

You can also target IE in your source code, and force it to load a seperate style sheet to the other browsers.

In your source code's head put:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all_ie_only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then, in your css directory, create a file called 'all_ie_only.css'. Inside 'all_ie_only.css', write separate rules to get it working in IE.

I suspect more verbose rules should get it working:

```
body {
 background-image: url('bg1.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top;
}
```

Comment: This is not the problem. replacing the image with a 2kb image works. which means the syntax is good enough.

Comment: @user2391025 Right, well give more information, then. Source code. CSS. A link to jsfiddler.